# REACT- How do I do to submit the data in the database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, frontend, backend

I have developped all my frontend in REACT based on the use of 2 json files. Now, I want to submit a form, push&fetch data, save data from input fields when refreshing a tab. I have a potential architecture for my datatabse (MYSQL). What should I do next to get/push this info on my database? I never done web front/backend before.

Here my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/Tabs.jsx:1108-1231)

Comment: why do you think reasking the same question with the same words will give you different results?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115070/how-do-i-do-to-submit-the-data-in-the-database)

Comment: This question seems more focused to me comparing the precedent one ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do to submit the data in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115070/how-do-i-do-to-submit-the-data-in-the-database)

Comment: @Zokulko you should then edit the original question. Do not repost. If it is edited to meet the SO standards then it can be re-opened.

Comment: But the question is closed... Is it not a problem if I edit it ?

Comment: Deleting and reposting is also not recommended. You should be aware that these actions may trigger a suspension if you're not careful. The system is automated and takes deleted questions into account

Comment: No it's not a problem, you can edit a closed question.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know that...

Comment: Also I noticed that you put "REACT -" into the titles of all your questions. This is unnecessary. Just tag them appropriately and keep the title short and to the point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use axios, and for method you can use POST
like this:

```js
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/store-data', {
        method: 'POST',
              }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      });
 
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

You use this event `handleSubmit` on your button.